# Django database queries are slow

Tags: python, mysql, django

I've been running into performance issues with Django selecting, what I consider, to be medium sized queries.

Here is an example of running a django query directly in Mysql;

```
SELECT * FROM `website_datapoolposition` WHERE (`website_datapoolposition`.`data_pool_id` = 596 AND `website_datapoolposition`.`timestamp` <= '2015-01-24 23:31:33' AND `website_datapoolposition`.`timestamp` >= '2015-01-24 19:01:30');
```

8063 rows in set (0.05 sec)

That seems very reasonable to me.  There are ~7million rows in this table, timestamp is indexed.

However when django pulls this data in as values, it takes .7 seconds.  Is django suppose to add a 14x overhead to raw sql?  I've googled for every trick I can find, nothing seems to get me down to ~80ms like I'd expect.

EDIT:

Here is the django def for this table:

```
#define my models
id          = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
car         = models.ForeignKey(Car)
lat         = models.DecimalField( max_digits=16, decimal_places=12 )
lng         = models.DecimalField( max_digits=16, decimal_places=12 )
speed       = models.DecimalField( max_digits=5, decimal_places=2, default=0 )
total = models.DecimalField( max_digits=12, decimal_places=2, null=True, blank=True)
dist        = models.DecimalField( max_digits=12, decimal_places=2, null=True, blank=True)
timestamp   = models.DateTimeField( db_index=True )
```

Here is the schema from show create table:

```
app_pos | CREATE TABLE `app_pos` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`lat` decimal(16,12) NOT NULL,
`lng` decimal(16,12) NOT NULL,
`speed` decimal(5,2) NOT NULL,
`timestamp` datetime NOT NULL,
`car_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`total` decimal(12,2) DEFAULT NULL,
`dist` decimal(12,2),
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
KEY `app_pos_fa16e375` (`car_id`),
KEY `app_pos_timestamp_f13fe0c76a90341_uniq` (`timestamp`),
KEY `app_pos_timestamp_343244cae95f1483_uniq` (`timestamp`),
CONSTRAINT     `app_dat_car_id_feb2a18963295a287_fk_app_car_id` FOREIGN   KEY (`car_id`) REFERENCES `app_car` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=7000000 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Comment: Without knowing your schema, its almost impossible to deduce why its slower. You can either modify your query to only select the fields you are interested in or use the ORM as it was built for.

Comment: Can you also show us the django query you have used to pull the data? Have you inspected the SQL query that django has executed? Try profiling tools like django-debug-toolbar.

Comment: The select statement above is the one I copied directly from the django-debug-toolbar.

Comment: Added the schema as well.

Answer (score 0):

When you run this query in MySQL cli you get the time of query execution at the server but not the time of transferring the rows to another process (or even machine) and build 8K heavy objects from these rows.

The fastest django-way to get data from SQL is:

```
data = DataPoolPosition.objects.filter(...).values_list('field1', 'field2')
```

You will get the iterator where each row will be represented by the tuple.

Another option is to [execute custom SQL](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/db/sql/#executing-custom-sql-directly) directly but I don't think that you will get a big speed improvement over the `values_list()` option.

Comment: I've tried both those things, the performance change wasn't noticeable.  I was surprised that the direct execution of the select statement through a connection cursor was the same speed.  Thank you for the examples.

Answer (score 0):

```
ADD INDEX(data_pool_id, timestamp)
```

(And SHOW CREATE TABLE so we know what we are working with.)